# Jquery #id linked event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an element to flash upon linking to its id, very much the way it is done here on stackoverflow. For example, whenever you append a page link with an element's id, it will take you to that element on the page:

```
<div id="some_element_id"></div>

url example: www.some_website.com/some_page#some_element_id
```

Is there an event I can use to then flash that element? maybe something like:

```
$('#some_element_id').link_event().fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500)
```

I am a little lost as to how this is done. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash;
}

$( getHash() ).link_event()..fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use the `window.location.hash`:

```
$(window.location.hash).link_event().fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500)
```

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers, there's an event for that called [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange).

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $(location.hash).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
});
```